# Calculating within, between or overall R-square in R

Tags: r, stata, panel-data, plm

I'm migrating from Stata to R (`plm package`) in order to do panel model econometrics. In Stata, panel models such  as random effects usually report the within, between and overall R-squared.

[I have found](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-September/289020.html) that the reported R-squared in the `plm` Random Effects models corresponds to the within R squared. So, is there any way to get the overall and between R-squared using the `plm package` in R?

See same example with R and Stata:

```
library(plm)
library(foreign) # read Stata files
download.file('http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/wagepan.dta','wagepan.dta',mode="wb")
wagepan <- read.dta('wagepan.dta')

# Random effects
plm.re <- plm(lwage ~ educ + black + hisp + exper + expersq + married + union + d81 + d82 + d83 + d84 + d85 + d86 + d87,
              data=wagepan,
              model='random',
              index=c('nr','year'))
summary(plm.re)
```

In Stata:

```
use http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/wagepan.dta
xtset nr year
xtreg lwage educ  black  hisp  exper  expersq  married  union  d81  d82  d83  d84  d85  d86  d87, re
```

The R-squared reported in R (0.18062) is, at least in this case, similar to the R-sq Within reported in Stata (0.1799). Is there any way to get in R the R-sq Between (0.1860) and overall (0.1830) reported in Stata?

Comment: @atiretoo please see now the reproducible example for both cases.

Comment: Spelling has been "Stata" for 30 years. More importantly, this is off-topic on CV. I'm voting to migrate.

Comment: This is a good question, but Nick is right in that it is off-topic. Perhaps it could be better answered by people at Stack Overflow.

Comment: please note that your indicated source is about fixed effect regression, not random effects.

Comment: @Helix123 Sorry, I don't understand your comment. For clarity, this example corresponds to example 14.4 in Wooldridge Introductory Econometrics where they estimate a Pooled OLS, a Random Effects and a Fixed Effects model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this website](http://www.urfie.net/downloads14.html) has the complete code to reproduce Example 14.4 in Wooldridge 2013 p. 494-5 with R-sq. reported for all models,

```
# install.packages(c("wooldridge"), dependencies = TRUE) 
# devtools::install_github("JustinMShea/wooldridge")
library(wooldridge) 
data(wagepan)

# install.packages(c("plm", "stargazer","lmtest"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(plm); library(lmtest); library(stargazer)

model <- as.formula("lwage ~ educ + black + hisp + exper+I(exper^2)+married + union+yr")
reg.ols <- plm(model, data = wagepan.p, model="pooling")

reg.re <- plm(lwage ~ educ + black + hisp + exper +
              I(exper^2) + married + union + yr, data = wagepan.p, model="random") 

reg.fe <- plm(lwage ~ I(exper^2) + married+union+yr, data=wagepan.p, model="within")

# Pretty table of selected results (not reporting year dummies)
stargazer(reg.ols,reg.re,reg.fe, type="text",
     column.labels=c("OLS","RE","FE"),
     keep.stat=c("n","rsq"),
     keep=c("ed","bl","hi","exp","mar","un"))
```

which outputs,

```
#> ==========================================
#>                   Dependent variable:     
#>              -----------------------------
#>                          lwage            
#>                 OLS       RE        FE    
#>                 (1)       (2)       (3)   
#> ------------------------------------------
#> educ         0.091***  0.092***           
#>               (0.005)   (0.011)           
#>                                           
#> black        -0.139*** -0.139***          
#>               (0.024)   (0.048)           
#>                                           
#> hisp           0.016     0.022            
#>               (0.021)   (0.043)           
#>                                           
#> exper        0.067***  0.106***           
#>               (0.014)   (0.015)           
#>                                           
#> I(exper2)    -0.002*** -0.005*** -0.005***
#>               (0.001)   (0.001)   (0.001) 
#>                                           
#> married      0.108***  0.064***   0.047** 
#>               (0.016)   (0.017)   (0.018) 
#>                                           
#> union        0.182***  0.106***  0.080*** 
#>               (0.017)   (0.018)   (0.019) 
#>                                           
#> ------------------------------------------
#> Observations   4,360     4,360     4,360  
#> R2             0.189     0.181     0.181  
#> ==========================================
#> Note:          *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP.
The question is how to get 3 different R^2s for one model. Not R^2s for three models.
The key should be in looking Stata's documentation on what it means by those 3 R^2s!